# need help converting C# foreach loop to lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, ienumerable, iqueryable

Can the following loop be implemented using IQueryable, IEnumerable or lambda expressions with linq

```
private bool functionName(int r, int c)
{
    foreach (S s in sList)
    {
        if (s.L.R == r && s.L.C == c)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

if so how?

Comment: Question doesn't make sense and is too open ended. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and revise your question.

Comment: The fun part is that even with these incomplete homework questions, we are answering to grab a tiny little bit of reputation :) The system works too well!

Comment: @Philippe And you're helping people like me, who are not too familiar with Lambdas. I simple wasn't aware of the .any

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
private bool functionName(int r, int c)
{
    return sList.Any(s => s.L.R == r && s.L.C == c);
}
```

The Any extension method in Linq applies to an IEnumerable sequence (which could be a List for example) and returns true if any of the items in the sequence return true for the given predicate (in this case a Lambda function `s => s.L.R == r && s.L.C == c`).

Answer (score 6):

something like:

```
return sList.Any(s => s.L.R == r && s.L.C == c);
```

Answer (score 0):

since you should provide more information about the classes (s.L.R ??) you use and I don't know what you really want as outcome of the function, this is not 100 percent sure:

```
return sList.Any(s => s.L.R == r && s.L.C == c);
```

/e: seems like I was a bit to late, sorry guys. Was not copiying yours.

Answer (score -1):

One example

```
private bool functionName(int r,int c)
{
  var ret = from s in sList where s.L.R==r&&s.L.C==c select s;
  return ret.Count()>0;
}
```